# Is this a binary operation (second time)?

Tags: group-theory, binary-operations

I was reading about order of an element in a group and came across this example, but I am unable to understand or imagine how it could be a group. Can someone explain ? [image]

Comment: What is the book?

Comment: If this is a verbatim copy out of a book, you should throw it away. It doesn't define a binary operation, only the elements of a (small) set, and even that not really, because it doesn't specify the direction of the rotation. I **guess** the binary operation is meant to be composition of those rotations.

Comment: The suggested orders are incorrect.  The correct orders are $1,3,3$ respectively.  See [order on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(group_theory)).  Perhaps you'll have an easier time recognizing this group with different labels.  It acts the same as $(\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z,+)$ where you have $[1]+[1]=[2], [1]+[2]=[0], [2]+[2]=[1], \dots$  Another way to see it is as the set of complex numbers $(\{1,-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i,-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i\},\cdot)$  There is after all only one group structure on a group of three elements possible.  You don't get variety until 4

Comment: I don't know the book as it was a part of some notes on group theory that i got from somewhere.. I agree with Vector that no extra information is given, I was wondering may be I am not able to understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition doesn't make much sense. What the author could have meant is a group $(G,+)$ where $G = \{0^\circ, 120^\circ, 240^\circ\}$ and the operation $+$ takes two elements of $G$ and adds them together so that, for example, $0^\circ + 120^\circ = 120^\circ$ and $240^\circ + 240^\circ = 120^\circ$ (since the angle $480^\circ$ is the same as $120^\circ$).

The identity element of the group would then be $0^\circ$ and the order of $0^\circ$ would thus be one. That of $120^\circ$ would be three since $$3\cdot 120^\circ=360^\circ\equiv 0^\circ,$$ and that of $240^\circ$ would also be three as $$3\cdot240^\circ=720^\circ\equiv 0^\circ.$$